# How to Launch streamlit local server from within nativefier

Tags: python, streamlit

This excellent thread [Streamlit Deployment as an Executable File](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/streamlit-deployment-as-an-executable-file-exe-for-windows-macos-and-android/6812/36)
shows how to deploy a website as an executable using the smart-tool, nativefier.

```
nativefier --name appname http://localhost:8501 --platform windows \
--icon ../apps/icon.ico --clear-cache --single-instance
```

The command above generates an executable appname.exe which when double-clicked will open localhost:8501, or other website indicated by the url-link above.

For a website on localhost, you need to start the local server beforehand. This issue on nativefier github [issue # 639](https://github.com/nativefier/nativefier/issues/639) implies I should be able to start the local server before I navigate to localhost:8501. However, the link is broken and I cannot locate the info on nativerfier's docs.

I simply would like to start the streamlit local server:

```
streamlit run app.py --server.headless true
```

before navigating to the localhost:8501 using the executable generated by nativefier. thanks for any pointers.